# How do I define the end and start date in date picker(flutter)?

Tags: flutter

I have built a custome scrollable date picker in the flutter and i dont know how to limit the display of the date[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofFeg.png)[code of date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73LTD.png)[Date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4LWC.png)

I want the program to diplay upto 7 date from the current date.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a custom Date Picker, just use the built-in one:

```dart
DateTime? dateTime = showDatePicker(
   initialDate: DateTime.now(),
   firstDate: DateTime.now(),
   lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7)),
(...)
```

Here, you can set the bouds yourself. This is an example for the time range now-in 7 days